# DNS lookups in php - how to use external name server

Tags: php, dns

I'm running a simple php script that loops through a list of URLs and does a DNS lookup and saves the A record in a database. Runs perfectly on my local server but when I put it on my live server, the records are all internal 192... because its using the internal DNS server.

I'm using Net_DNS2 and have told it to use google DNS:

```
$r = new Net_DNS2_Resolver(array('nameservers' => array('8.8.8.8')));
```

but this doesnt seem to be working, I still get back 192 internal addresses.

Any ideas how to resolve this? I already moved to Net_DNS2 from the php dns_get_record function so that I could set a nameserver, but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Why should an internal name server deliver internal addresses for external resources? Or are those URLs inside that local network? With hosts specifically defined inside that local DNS server? That is not exactly common...

Comment: Yes this is the problem the URLs i'm looking up are on other servers within the same network, so the DNS just gets an internal IP for it. I need my DNS function to lookup in external servers. The response from Net_DS2 looks like this:


    Net_DNS2_Packet_Response Object
(
    [answer_from] => 8.8.8.8

which suggests I have set this ip properly, but it is not using it for results, the servers internal dns server is overriding it somehow.

Comment: Maybe there is some cache in between?